# Best option for DNS management

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hosting

From last few days traffic on website(https://www.fanspole.com/) is too high, so we are trying to optimise website. One thing I notice was DNS resolve time is too high..

```
@MacBook-Air ~ $ ping fanspole.com
PING fanspole.com (139.162.35.126): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 139.162.35.126: icmp_seq=0 ttl=56 time=717.688 ms
64 bytes from 139.162.35.126: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=606.560 ms
64 bytes from 139.162.35.126: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=654.942 ms
64 bytes from 139.162.35.126: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=677.301 ms
64 bytes from 139.162.35.126: icmp_seq=4 ttl=56 time=699.991 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
64 bytes from 139.162.35.126: icmp_seq=6 ttl=56 time=601.355 ms
64 bytes from 139.162.35.126: icmp_seq=7 ttl=56 time=660.974 ms
64 bytes from 139.162.35.126: icmp_seq=8 ttl=56 time=605.084 ms
--- fanspole.com ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 8 packets received, 20.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 601.355/652.987/717.688/42.087 ms
```

we are using Linode DNS Manager as of now..
Can someone suggest better alternatives.

Comment: did you manage to sort this?

Answer (score 0):

This is *not* a DNS resolution issue, its a network congestion issue.

`traceroute to 139.162.35.126 (139.162.35.126), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
<internal hops removed>
 4  10gigabitethernet5-1.core1.lon1.he.net (5.57.80.128)  22.367 ms  22.618 ms  22.841 ms
 5  10ge2-9.core1.lon2.he.net (72.52.92.222)  24.056 ms  24.277 ms  24.500 ms
 6  100ge1-1.core1.nyc4.he.net (72.52.92.166)  94.769 ms  93.549 ms  93.694 ms
 7  100ge14-2.core1.sjc2.he.net (184.105.81.213)  156.692 ms  147.815 ms  147.974 ms
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  xe0-2-0.gw1.sin2.pacnet.net (202.147.52.66)  320.731 ms  321.978 ms  321.950 ms
11  * * *
12  139.162.0.10 (139.162.0.10)  252.825 ms  251.826 ms  251.285 ms
13  li1448-126.members.linode.com (139.162.35.126)  251.746 ms  252.270 ms  251.406 ms`

That is a traceroute from London UK - you can see on line 7 when it hits the `he.net` it starts to pick up latency. By the time it gets to line 10 in `pacnet.net` its 300+ms

The only option here is to move to a different Linode region or different hosting provider with better/less congested network links.